# Could someone tell me how this is derived?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, conditional-probability

I am referring to the solution to Exercise 7.39(c) in the book *Probability and Random Processes for Electrical and Computer Engineers*, and find one step of derivation hard to understand.
The problem is here:

> Use the law of total probability to solve the following problems:
>
> (c) Evaluate $\text{E}[Xe^Y]$ if $X \sim \text{uniform}[3, 7]$, and given $X = x$, $Y \sim N(0, x^2)$.

The solution is here:

> Begin in the usual way by writing
> $$\begin{align}
> \text{E}[Xe^Y] &=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{E}[Xe^Y \mid X = x]f_{X}(x)\text{ d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{E}[xe^Y \mid X = x]f_{X}(x)\text{ d}x \\
> &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\text{E}[e^Y \mid X = x]f_{X}(x)\text{ d}x
> \end{align}$$
> Now observe that
> $$\text{E}[e^Y \mid X = x] = \left.\text{E}[e^{sY} \mid X = x]\right|_{s=1}= \left.e^{s^2x^2/2}\right|_{s=1} = e^{x^2/2}\text{.}$$

Can someone tell me how the step $E[e^{sY}|X=x]|_{s=1} =  e^{s^2x^2/2}|_{s=1}$ in part(c) is derived? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you learned about moment-generating functions? If not, this will be more complicated than you'd probably like.

Comment: @Clarinetist Yes I've learned that, please enlighten me! (By the way how did you turn the image into formulas?  I am new to this website :) )

Comment: Math StackExchange uses MathJax, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the moment-generating function (MGF) of a random variable $Y$ is $\mathbb{E}[e^{tY}]$.

In this case, observe that the MGF of $Y \mid X = x$ is thus $\mathbb{E}[e^{tY} \mid X = x]$.

Recall also that if $Z \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ that its MGF is given by
$$M_{Z}(s) = \exp\left(\mu s+ \dfrac{\sigma^2}{2}s^2 \right)\text{.}$$
Thus, since $Y \mid (X = x) \sim N(0, x^2)$,
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{sY} \mid X = x] = \exp\left(0s + \dfrac{x^2}{2}s^2 \right) = e^{s^2x^2/2}\text{.}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! For both the question and the MathJax :)

Comment: Bo problem indeed

Answer (score 0):

A different but equivalent approach is the following:

$$\mathbb{E}[Xe^Y]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Xe^Y|X]]=\mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{E}[e^Y|X]]$$

Now observe that

$$Z=(e^Y|X=x)\sim \text{Lognormal}(0;x^2)$$

([Here is the link to the lognormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution))

Thus

$$\mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{E}[e^Y|X]]=\mathbb{E}[Xe^{\frac{X^2}{2}}]=\frac{1}{4}\int_3^7xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=\frac{e^{\frac{9}{2}}(e^{20}-1)}{4}$$